# How to query a Postgres DB in node.js (api.ai,node.js)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, dialogflow-es

I have the following function in a node.js app:

```
if (parameters.hasOwnProperty("brand-param") && parameters["brand-param"] !='') {
    codes.readCodes(function(allCodes) {
```

the function readCodes is then called and within the function, I query the db:

```
readCodes: function(callback) {
      var pool = new pg.Pool(config.PG_CONFIG);
      pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {
          if (err) {
              return console.error('Error acquiring client', err.stack);
          }
          client
              .query(
                  `SELECT brand_code FROM public.voucher_codes WHERE brand_name=${parameters.hasOwnProperty("brand-param")} `,
                  function(err, result)
```

How do I query the db with the content of the “brand-param” for the WHERE part?

Comment: You forgot to specify the id according to the part `brand_name=$1` like it's done above `[userId],`

Comment: The `$1` in the request mean that you gonna specify a variable. `WHERE brand_name=$1', ['JOHN'], function(err, result) {` would work. Either for  `WHERE brand_name="JOHN"', function(err, result) {`

Comment: In that I can't help! It depends of the functionality you want to implement. :P

Comment: I updated the question. The comments up to this point were for a previous issue which was partially resolved in rewriting the function.

Comment: replace `parameters.hasOwnProperty("brand-param")` by `parameters["brand-param"]`. `hasOwnProperty` look if the key exist in the object so you were only passing `brand_name=true`

Comment: I tried that one but get `ReferenceError: parameters is not defined`. The first function is in apps.js, it then calls the function readCodes which is in codes.js and then the error is triggered - I don't understand why its not defined if its there in apps.js?

Comment: Pass the variable to the `readCodes` function like `codes.readCodes(parameters, function(allCodes) {`. Adapt readCodes aswell tho as `readCodes: function(parameters, callback) {`. I guess the variable `parameters` is local.

Comment: Progress, I feel so close. `[!] Error: { error: column "football" does not exist` With that query, its seems to be looking for a column called Football when it should be looking in the column brand_name for football.

Comment: Ok try `brand_name="${parameters["brand-param"]}" `

Comment: I think I tried that with what I commented out as I get the same result with that:

readCodes: function(parameters, callback) {
    //var paramString = parameters["brand-param"];
  
                //  `SELECT brand_code FROM public.voucher_codes WHERE brand_name=${paramString} `,
                `SELECT brand_code FROM public.voucher_codes WHERE brand_name="${parameters["brand-param"]}"`,

(the quotes used are the same as the code markdown so apologies) Its still looking for a column of that name when it should be looking inside the column 'brand_name' for football

Comment: Ok it should work I see no problem on the request. So what to do now : try without `WHERE` clause and see if you get any data you should see them all. Then try to use fix brand_name in your query `SELECT brand_code FROM public.voucher_codes WHERE brand_name="football"`. If that work, you know the problem is about how you use the parameter. If that don't look at your database to see if your table is well formatted

Comment: I think its to do with the quotes. The err in postgre is reproduced with `WHERE brand_name="football"`

It works as it should with `WHERE brand_name='football'`

So the function needs to be changed to pass as single quotes?

Comment: Ok you got it :) I never used postgre so i didn't knew about it. Single quotes it is. So `SELECT brand_code FROM public.voucher_codes WHERE brand_name='${parameters["brand-param"]}'`

Comment: I can't believe it worked. It's completely messed up the function in terms of what it was meant to do but the key part is now working, thanks to you. The key parts were not passing the parameter and then not querying correctly. Its been a cracking journey because as I said, last week node.js and programming in general was alien to me. Not sure how I award answer but you got me there!!!! Thank you Grégory.

Comment: I'm gonna post the resume of what we have said as an answer and you could accept it :). Good it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The variable `parameters` defined inside `apps.js` must be passed to `readCodes` function in order to use it in the query.
2. The check of `brand_name` is incorrect. It miss the use of `single quotes` and the parameter value itself is incorrect.

---

```
if (parameters['brand-param'] && parameters['brand-param'].length) {
    codes.readCodes(parameters, function(allCodes) {
```

---

```
readCodes: function(parameters, callback) {
  var pool = new pg.Pool(config.PG_CONFIG);

  pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {
      if (err) {
          return console.error('Error acquiring client', err.stack);
      }

 client.query(
   `SELECT brand_code FROM public.voucher_codes WHERE brand_name='${parameters['brand-param']}' `,
    function(err, result)
```

Comment: Hi Grégory. I manipulated the function to get the desired result. Its not catching an undefined though. 

`callback(result.rows[0]['brand_code']);
TypeError: Cannot read property 'brand_code' of undefined`

Its running the following when the value is undefined:

`} else if (['brand_code'] != null ) {
                                callback(result.rows[0]['brand_code']);`

Any ideas?

Comment: `} else if (result.rows[0] && typeof result.rows[0]['brand_code'] !== 'undefined') { callback(result.rows[0]['brand_code']);`

Comment: I shall give it a go tomorrow. Thank you very much Grégory.